# UIPicker - selectRow:12 inComponent:0 animated:NO not working (12 or more than 12)

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview, uipicker

I am facing a weird issue for UIPicker.

I have `UIPicker` where I am showing some states of US. By default random selection is already done. For that  I am using below statement.

```
[statesPicker selectRow:myRegPos inComponent:0 animated:NO];
```

**However**, this statement is ONLY working if `myRegPos <= 11`.

When I have `myRegPos >= 12`, default first option is getting selected. Any idea why this is happening?

### When `myRegPos = 2`

[image]

### When `myRegPos >= 12`

[image]

To confirm how many rows we have, I see in

```
- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

Here I print the number that return and it is 64.

***Any idea why this is happening?***

---

For title I use

```
if ([tappedWhat isEqualToString:@"states"]) {
        return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[feedsStates objectAtIndex:row] objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"NameS"]]];
}
```

### My concern is

When it works with

`[statesPicker selectRow:3 inComponent:0 animated:NO];`

### why not with

`[statesPicker selectRow:12 inComponent:0 animated:NO];`?

***NOOOOOOO..... This is really making me crazy. Any idea what is going wrong? It's 2 days, but NO SOLUTION :(***

Comment: where did you put this line in your class: `[statesPicker selectRow:myRegPos inComponent:0 animated:NO];`?

Comment: @holex : I have this line after parsing is done... I am bringing random number from webservice and I use that number after I did the parsing... so I have in `- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {`

Comment: `[statesPicker selectRow:12 inComponent:0 animated:NO];` make sure it is called after the pickerView is configured.

Comment: @KudoCC : If configuration was problem then `[statesPicker selectRow:3 inComponent:0 animated:NO];` SHOULD HAVE NOT BEEN WORKED

Comment: Ok, upload your project is the fastest way to solve it.

Comment: @KudoCC : I cannot give webservice and all project... :D :P Its a company project and I cant put 50 MB Project...

Comment: In `- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component`, do you just `return [feedsStates count] ;`. If so , `NSLog(@"%u", [feedsStates count])` before you call `[statesPicker selectRow:12 inComponent:0 animated:NO] ;`.

Comment: @KudoCC : it says 64...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you made sure that your view controller implements both UIPickerViewDataSource and  UIPickerViewDelegate protocols. And that 64 rows is defined by you in the **pickerView:numberOfRowsInComponent:**

How did you implement the **titleForRow** method? Did you put all 64 titles? Or did do implement only 12 states?

```
-(NSString*)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component;
```

Answer (score 0):

call `[statesPicker  reloadAllComponents] ;` and make sure `feedsStates` is filled with the data before selecting 12th row.

```
NSAssert([[NSThread currentThread] isMainThread], @"error") ;
NSAssert(statesPicker != nil, @"error") ;
NSAssert([feedsStates count] >= 12, @"error") ;
[statesPicker  reloadAllComponents] ;
[statesPicker selectRow:12 inComponent:0 animated:NO] ;
```

Comment: @FahimParkar Update my answer, hope it helps.

Comment: I am sorry, but what this NSAssert will do? I don't get any wording as error... just NSLog of feeds count... which is still 64.. **& still first row is selected**

Comment: @FahimParkar Do you call it in the main thread? Updated answer to test if it is in the main thread.

Comment: @FahimParkar You can create a demo and do similar things. If it still has the error, upload the project.